# How to resolve build errors while integrating gmime into VS2010 project?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use gmime in a vc++ project I'm working on.
I have gmime dependent dll, lib and header files.

Trying to build the first example from the tutorial fails horribly however.
This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ssize_t long
#include <gmime/gmime.h>

    int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
        GMimeStream *stream;

        /* initialize GMime */
        g_mime_init (0);

        /* create a stream around stdout */
        stream = g_mime_stream_file_new (stdout);

        /* 'printf' */
        g_mime_stream_printf (stream, "Hello World!\n");

        /* flush stdout */
        g_mime_stream_flush (stream);

        /* free/close the stream */
        g_object_unref (stream);

        return 0;
    }
```

While build the vc++ project, I am getting following error,

> ```
> Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'GMimeStream'
>   Error   C2059   syntax error: ''
>   Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before ''
>   Error   C2086   'int ssize_t': redefinition
>   Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   Error   C2086   'int GMimeStream': redefinition
> ```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.